# How to do an if statement in a while loop or vice versa

Tags: php, wordpress, events, if-statement, while-loop

I'm working on The Events Calendar Pro plugin for wordpress and I need a little help. I think its simple but I can't figure it out.

Basically, there is an additional field I can add to each event. I want to check if that field is set and if it is set, then I want that particular event to display on the homepage.

I'm trying to somehow mix a code that I did on another site's homepage template with the plugin widgets file.

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
<?php
$query_str = "SELECT distinct wposts.ID FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id  AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '_EventStartDate' 
AND wposts.post_type = 'tribe_events' ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC ";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results( $query_str );
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    $id=get_the_ID();
    $linkr=get_post_meta($id,'_ecp_custom_3',true);

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $todayDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $eventDate=get_post_meta($id,'_EventEndDate', "Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if ((strtolower($linkr)=='yes') && ($eventDate >= $todayDate)) {
        $link=get_permalink($id);
        echo "<li><a href='{$link}' title=''>";
        the_post_thumbnail();
        echo "</a></li>";
    }
}?>
```

And here is the code I'm using in the widget file. This is the one where I want to check if that additional field is set, if it is, then add to homepage but I don't understand how to tweak it with while loop.

```
<div class="tribe-venue-widget-wrapper">
<ul>
<?php while ( $events->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php $events->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php tribe_get_event_link() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</ul>
```

Here is what I came up with and doesn't work correctly:

```
<div class="tribe-venue-widget-wrapper">
<ul>
<?php while ( $events->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php $events->the_post();
        foreach($events as $event){
            setup_postdata($event);
            $id=get_the_ID();
            $showOnHomepage=get_post_meta($id,'_ecp_custom_4',true);
            $eventDate=get_post_meta($id,'_EventEndDate', "Y-m-d H:i:s");

            if (($showOnHomepage == 'Yes') && ($eventDate >= $todayDate)) {
                $link=get_permalink($id);
                echo "<li><a href='{$link}' title=''>";
                the_post_thumbnail('medium');
                echo "</a></li>";
            }
        }
    ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to set the default timezone every time through the loop. Just set it once before the loop. The same with `$todayDate` -- it's not going to change.

Comment: Oh, so put it outside of the loop...got it.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking for. What is the additional field you want to test for? What do you want to show when that field is set? I don't see how the two code blocks are even related -- the first is processing database results, the second is using something called `$events`.

Comment: Maybe it will make sense to someone who knows WordPress, I've added the tag.

Comment: Yes the 2 aren't exactly related but they do the same thing in a way. The top one I put into my homepage template so it searches the database for events with the post type tribe events.

The 2nd one is code that's already within that events plugin. So instead of using $post it's using $events and I just don't get how to make it work. 

Basically I'm trying to check if that _ecp_custom_3 is set to "Yes". If it is, display only those events in a list order. 

That's the part I don't understand how to incorporate into the 2nd piece of code above.

Comment: I added a 3rd piece of code block where I incorporated both code into one. But it's still not working correctly.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the new code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not quite sure what you need but best guess is below.

```
<?php
$events = new wp_query(//is this present in your code?--if not $events has no posts. 
);
?>

<div class="tribe-venue-widget-wrapper">
<ul>

<?php while ( $events->have_posts() ):
    $events->the_post();



        $showOnHomepage=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_ecp_custom_4',true);
        $eventDate=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_EventEndDate', true); //boolan here you can change formats after if you want -- true= single result false = multiple if exist

        if (($showOnHomepage == 'Yes') && ($eventDate >= $todayDate)) {
            $link=get_permalink();
            echo "<li><a href='{$link}' title=''>";
            the_post_thumbnail('medium');
            echo "</a></li>";
        }
    }
   endwhile; 
   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to all this. What would I put in wp_query()? Can you give me an example?

Comment: no problem, a lot of options e.g. post types, meta querys, taxonomy querys etc. see the link for all the options, but if you just want all your posts `wp_query('post_type' => 'post');` .... http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that sometime today when I get back on that project.